# Modules with different CPU types as a reason of exception in java program

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface, mingw

I created dll to use it in my java program, but after program start I receive an exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Testing of dll using Dependency Walker gave such a message

> Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
>
> Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

I work with Win7 x64 but dll was created using MinGW so it is 32-bit library.
Can it be the reason of exception in java program?

Comment: [Take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103220/why-does-msvc-2010-32bit-project-link-to-64bit-kernel32-dll)

Comment: @DavidRF thank you for the quick answer. It seems the reasin is really in module search order of Dependency Walker. It is good and at the same time bad news because now I have not any idea what can be the reason of exception in java program. I compared all the methods declarations from my genereted header file and my realized methods - everything is fine but exception still exists:(

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747)? maybe your problem could be fixed using `CD \windows\syswow64` `regsvr32 filename.dll`