# C# Dll import not working with some computers

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a C++ dll compiled using VS2013.

I call it in my C# application like this :

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "RestartIfNecessary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool RestartIfNecessary(uint uiAppId);
```

And it works fine.

However once the application is in prod some users have the following error :
Unable to load DLL 'myDLL.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I can't find why this error happens on some computers. We've been able to fix the issue for some users by removing  Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) and (x64) and installing them again.

My C# application is compiled to run on x86.
I have a 64bits w10 and it works fine, so I don't know if it's related to windows.

Have you any hint to help me fixing this issue ?

EDIT: Here are the results of dependency walker :

[image]

In dependendy walker I've found 3 dll in red, I don't know if they are important:
[image]

API.dll is a third party dll (myDLL is a wrapper for this API)

Answer (score 2):

The error means either `myDLL.dll` itself, or one of its dependent DLLs, cannot be found on the [DLL search path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx).

Make sure `myDLL.dll` is placed where your app can find it. You can load `myDLL.dll` into [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the problematic computers to pinpoint any missing dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, i've edited and added the result of dependency walker.

Comment: Can you please retry inserting the dependency walker results? I only see [![enter code here][1]][1] in your post

Comment: You will find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103220/why-does-msvc-2010-32bit-project-link-to-64bit-kernel32-dll)

Comment: Thank you, I've asked him to use the x86 version. Please see my edit with the new result.

Comment: So the dependencies ext-ms-win-wlan-onexui-l1-1-0.dll and ieshims.dll are missing. Try looking them up on the disk using the [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/Everything-1.3.4.686.x64-Setup.exe) utility